# Using an array in Azure web app settings

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

In my ASP.NET 5 (RC1) code I have an appsetting.json that looks something like this:

```
{
    "SomeSettings": {
        "PropA": "ValueA",
        "PropB": [
            "ValueB1",
            "ValueB2"
        ]
    }
}
```

These value are used when a run the code on my dev machine (ie. localhost). If I want to overwrite the "SomeSettings" in Azure's Application settings for the wep app, how would I specify the "PropB" array?

The SomeSettings.cs class that I want to store the information in looks like this:

```
public class SomeSettings
{
    public string PropA { get; set; }
    public List<string> PropB { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is "PropB" - how to I specify an array or List as a string in Azure - is this even possible?

In my Startup class's constructor I have:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

And in my Startup class's Configure methods I have:

```
var someSettings = configuration.GetSection("SomeSettings").Get<SomeSettings>();
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Adding the settings under "App settings" like this will do the trick...
Notice the ":0" and ":1" below

Format: Key -> Value

```
SomeSettings:PropA -> AzureValueA
SomeSettings:PropB:0 -> AzureValueB1
SomeSettings:PropB:1 -> AzureValueB2
```

If you aren't running on Windows, replace the colon `:` with double underscore `__` to get your app to see the settings. So instead of e.g. `SomeSettings:PropB:1`, you'd use `SomeSettings__PropB__1`.

Comment: As of today it works great. Just want to confirm approach is still here. We use VSTS to deploy WebApp arguments via PS scripts, now we can push arrays. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how you would represent `SomeSettings__PropB` as an empty array?

Comment: This also works in Azure Functions' local.settings.json.

Comment: Don't forget to add `Values` prefix in setting name if you are using Azure Function. 
i.e. `Values:SomeSettings:PropB:0`

Comment: What if you have an unnamed array of objects instead of plain values, how would you set that? I tried `SomeSettings__PropA__object__value` but I can't seem to set it correctly.

Comment: for windows would it be SomeSettings__PropA:1 or SomeSettings__PropA__1 ?

Comment: For an unnamed array of object use `sectionName:0:PropA` `sectionName:0:PropB` `sectionName:1:PropA` `sectionName:1:PropB` etc. For Linux services replace `:` with double underscore `__`

Comment: This still works in 2023 on app services, for APIs or azure functions.

Answer (score 2):

In case the array value is an object (see that WriteTo value below) you can copy the entire WriteTo value, update the values if you need to and create an application setting for it as follows;

```
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights",
          "instrumentationKey": "YOUR-KEY"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "UmbracoFile",
        "Args": {
          "RestrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console"
            }
          ]
        }
      }

    ]
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I try to use if to feature management filters that has a crazy amount for properties and arrays. Is there anything special that needs to happen for this to work?

Comment: No, nothing special. It is exactly how I described it in my answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation the value should be like this:

```
['entry1', 'entry2', 'entry3']
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-arrays-in-app-settings

Comment: It's in the official documentation, but this doesn't work for me. The array that I have in my appsettings.json is not being overridden.

Comment: Since the linked doc doesn't seem to show anything about arrays anymore, here's something else that clarifies the obscure convention: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#naming-of-environment-variables
The double-underscore notation may or may not apply (obscure in its own right), but the key is that "the array index should be treated as an additional element name in this path".

Comment: this works fine for me, not sure if the array is making any difference ( options object is defined as array not list )  but I do have the configurations as an array and I use IOptions and it's working

Answer (score -10):

Simple approach is store the JSON as string in AppSetting, and de-serialize by yourself

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var settings = serializer.Deserialize<SomeSettings>(configuration.GetSection("SomeSettings"));
```

or you will have to create your own customer configuration i believe. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

Comment: The question is about "Azure web app settings", your answer is irrelevant.