# Missing value for AzureWebJobsStorage in local.settings.json local development in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I'm developing an Azure Function locally, with the Storage Emulator and de Storage Explorer opened.

**File tree**

[image: File tree]

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "PlantaoEntities": {
      "ConnectionString": "CENSORED",
      "ProviderName": "System.Data.EntityClient"
    }
  }
}
```

But I receive the following message when trying to run the code:

> Missing value for AzureWebJobsStorage in local.settings.json. This is required for all triggers other than HTTP. You can run 'func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings ' or specify a connection string in local.settings.json

It was working before I rebuilt the solution, and if I try `func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings <functionAppName>` then it tries to retrieve the information from the Azure Portal itself.

Comment: I had the same problem, here is the easiest solution I followed:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72983736/12824729

Answer (score 102, accepted):

> The solution was to right-click on local.settings.json, go to
>   properties, change "Copy to Output directory" from "Do not copy" to
>   "Copy always". Now the CLI picks up the settings when running from
>   within Visual Studio 2017.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/223#issuecomment-326225219

Comment: There is no "Properties"

Comment: This is only when you have your project on VS, not vscode with node.

Comment: @makitocode what's the solution in vscode with node?

Comment: @JonoSuave <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>

Comment: @SamiHuutoniemi Where do I add this configuration?

Comment: This worked for me in VS 2022 also

Answer (score 93):

I was getting the same error when I was running my `Azure Function` in my `Visual Studio 2019`.

[image]

I had already set the `Copy To Output Directory` action to `Copy always` and I was still getting the same error. The issue is that the Azure Function `local.settings.json` file doesn't support `nested json`. You can track this issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/223).

I was having values in `local.settings.json` as preceding.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "Custom": {
      "Tickets": {
        "Channels": [
          "One",
          "Two"
        ]
      }
    },
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ServiceBusConnectionString": ""
  }
}
```

As you can see that there is an extra nested json (Custom) object inside Values, that is the reason why I was getting this error. To fix this, I had to add a new configuration file called `configuration.json` and add my custom values there.

```
"Custom": {
      "Tickets": {
        "Channels": [
          "One",
          "Two"
        ]
      }
    }
```

The fix is to use either the `ConfigurationBuilder` or read that file using `File.ReadAllText`. You can also add the entire JSON as a plain string in the `local.settings.json` instead of a JSON object.

Or you can add the custom configs under the `Values JSON object` as below.

```
"CustomConfigs:Config1": "",
"CustomConfigs:Config2:Config3": ""
```

And use a binding in the `Startup` file.

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<CustomConfigs>()
.Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
{                    configuration.GetSection("CustomConfigs").Bind(settings);
});
```

Just make sure that **you clean the solution and build again** after the change above.

Comment: Thanks, this was it for me. In my case, I needed arrays, so I formatted my custom values like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34063168/348375, and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, this was the same thing that happened to me as well :)

Comment: This answer has now saved med twice as I forgot about the limitation and had the same problem in a brand new .net 6 function app created with vs2022. I see the issue has been closed as obsolete, not sure why if it is still an issue. Would be much easier if appsetting.json and local.settings.json behaved the same so I didn't have to keep track of stuff like this.

Answer (score 28):

FYI, you also get this error when the value for `"AzureWebJobsStorage"` is effectively empty (`""`). You can set it to e.g. `"UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` for development.

Be aware, this requires the storage emulator installed locally. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=linux%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#local-settings-file).

Answer (score 22):

Just saw this error on VS2019 and resolved it by reordering the local.settings.json so that the IsEncrypted value was after the "Values"

```
{
   "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "removed",
      },
   "IsEncrypted": false
}
```

Comment: Excellent! The other issues sounds reasonable enough but this solved it!

Comment: WT...... this works. Nothing was wrong in my local.settings.json because it worked with the same content before. Suddenly it stopped working. Tried everything, clean solution, rebuild, removing bin and obj dirs manually, restart laptop... Nothing worked. Now it does !!!

Comment: I hate that this is a valid answer because it is so stupid that we have to do things like that with MS config files. Order in a flat file for json should never matter.

Answer (score 15):

Same error appears when your `local.settings.json` file has a json error, e.g. to following commas `,,`.

Answer (score 8):

I know the question is related to Visual Studio, but I could fix the error by doing the following in Visual Studio Code:

1. Install the "Azurite" extension
2. Press *F1* and type *Azurite: Start*
3. Debug your Azure Function as usual (by pressing *F5*)

For more details see the [official documentation for Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite)

Answer (score 6):

In case any of the above solutions aren't working for people who require nested JSON in their local.settings.json, just flatten the nested objects as so:

This:

```
"Config": {
 "MyCusomValue": "Value"
}
```

Becomes:

```
"Config:MyCustomValue": "Value"
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that may have encountered this and scratched their heads because they didn't have nested JSON and had their `<ItemGroup>` values correct, this may help you. Since `local.settings.json` is ignored, I had copied one over using the file system, and though Visual Studio for Mac was showing it in the solution explorer it was apparently not picking it up no matter what I changed `<CopyToOutputDirectory>` to. After closing and reopening my solution the issue went away.

Comment: Same for me on Windows.  Something in visual studio is getting stuck...  It's funny that there are so many different issues out there when you search for problems and the azure functions support is so finicky that a simple VS restart is the last thing that came to mind.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Solution - Azure Functions Node.js/Typescript (VSCODE)**

This solution is for local development. Be aware, this requires the storage emulator installed locally. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=linux%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#local-settings-file).

1.) From your project root, open `local.settings.json` and update the `AzureWebJobsStorage` value from `""` to `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`.

example: `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",`

2.) Restart Function App

Example local.setting.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION": "Optional_your_remote_storage_string_in_azure"
    "AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME": "optional_remote_container_name"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have local.settings.json, its spelling is correct and cs proj must have:

```
<None Update="local.settings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could also happen if you declare an string array on the settings since it is not supported. I had something like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION": "Optional_your_remote_storage_string_in_azure"
    "AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME": "optional_remote_container_name",
    "AllowedTypesToProcess": 
    [
        "MyType1",
        "MyType2",
        "MyType3"
    ]
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071
  }
}
```

Since arrays are not supported, it failed to load the settings, but the error says "Missing value for AzureWebJobsStorage in local.settings.json"

If you need to have an array of the settings, take a look to this: https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/9256d500-5dbc-4375-851d-4d6f13928945/y

Answer (score 1):

I follow this and it works:

Modify your .csproj file to have this:

```
<None Update="local.settings.json">
<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
<CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
```

for more information, check this link:
https://www.koskila.net/how-to-fix-missing-value-for-azurewebjobsstorage-in-local-settings-json-when-youre-debugging-azure-functions-locally/

Answer (score 1):

Have fixed error by switching `Copy to Output Directory` property for `local.settings.json` file from `Copy if newer` to `Copy always`.

In my local `local.settings.json` file `AzureWebJobsStorage` contains actual connection copied from `Storage account` -> `Security + networking` -> `Access keys` -> `key1` -> `Connection string`

Answer (score 1):

in my case i had to do this

```
  <None Update="local.settings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your local.settings.json doesn't have an invalid value in it! For me a was missing a backslash, causing invalid character escaping in my connectiong string.

Answer (score 0):

For me I found this file to be very finicky so I set it back to the way it was created by VS2019 and added my own configuration as has been suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Update the local setting below

```
{
  "Values": 
  {
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=`connection string of a blob storage`",
  "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  },
  "IsEncrypted": false
}
```

Sample connection

```
string=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was missing a closing quote on one of my values. As soon as I fixed that, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to work by making sure the `connection` value ended with `_STORAGE`.

`function.json`

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "blob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "container/{name}",
      "connection": "mystorage_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

`local.settings.json`

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=yyy==;",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=yyy==;",
    "mystorage_STORAGE": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=yyy==;"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the spelling of the file local.settings.json is wrong, Visual Studio wont find it, but report that the values are not provided.

This is worked for me.

Please check the **local.settings.json** file name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check once if the **local.settings.json** is in the same level as the azure functions folder. The function expects the value in this way.

For example:

1. ```
    functions
    local.settings.json
        EventhubTrigger
           function.json
   ```
2. ```
    local.settings.json
    EventhubTrigger
        function.json
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I do not HAVE a local.settings.json file.

I have [Project] > Properties (folder) > launchSettings.json (file).

In the launchSettings.json file, set:
profiles > (project name) > environmentVariables > "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"

BTW, launchSettings.json file is set to "Do not copy"

Comment: This appears to answer a different question than asked, then, since that’s clearly not true of the OP’s setup. In cases like this, you can create a new question with specifics of your situation, and then post your own solution to it.

Answer (score -1):

I just encounter same issue with Intellij Idea (didn't wanted to move on VSCode).
I just had to download Azure Core tools depending on my system (Windows, forced by the client -_-) on :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash

Then edit the launch config, adding in App settings key :

```
AzureWebJobsStorage
```

And in App settings value :

```
UseDevelopmentStorage=true
```

Have fun.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this issue finally, it is because of your config files like local.settings.json or appsettings.json show any warning messages then it will fail to load the settings.

Answer (score -1):

Another gotcha:

If the spelling of the file `local.settings.json` is wrong, Visual Studio wont find it, but report that the values are not provided.