# How to configurate the Entity Famework Core with Azure Functions (Timer trigger) and azure sql?

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I actually have a database in Azure Sql and I have an Azure function (timer trigger) in another Azure account (different from the database) I have already used Core Entity framework to map the database but when I want to do queries it doesn’t work,so there’s something wrong with the configuration.I tried a lot and tried some solutions but I still couldn’t solve this problem. I’m uploading the code hoping you can help me. Thanks in advance.

****Function1.cs**:**

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;





namespace azuretosharepoint
{

    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            var azsh = new ProgettokpidatabaseContext();
            var listsharepoint = azsh.KpiTables.ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(listsharepoint);
                            
            
         }
    }
}
```

****progettokpidatabaseContext.cs**:**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

#nullable disable

namespace azuretosharepoint
{
    public partial class ProgettokpidatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProgettokpidatabaseContext()
        {
        }

        public ProgettokpidatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<ProgettokpidatabaseContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<KpiTable> KpiTables { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<KptKpiTarget> KptKpiTargets { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<KpvKpiValue> KpvKpiValues { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("sqlconnectionstring"));
               //#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
                //optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=tcp:progetto-kpi.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=progetto-kpi-database;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=progetto-kpi;Password=**********;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("Relational:Collation", "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");

            modelBuilder.Entity<KpiTable>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.KpiId);

                entity.ToTable("KPI_table");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpiId)
                    .ValueGeneratedNever()
                    .HasColumnName("KPI_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpiBusinessArea)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .HasColumnName("KPI_Business_Area");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpiDescription)
                    .HasMaxLength(250)
                    .HasColumnName("KPI_Description");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpiDoi)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasColumnName("KPI_DOI")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpiDou)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasColumnName("KPI_DOU")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpiFrequency)
                    .HasMaxLength(10)
                    .HasColumnName("KPI_Frequency");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpiManual).HasColumnName("KPI_Manual");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpiName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .HasColumnName("KPI_Name");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<KptKpiTarget>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.KptId)
                    .HasName("PK_KPT_table");

                entity.ToTable("KPT_KPI_Targets");

                entity.Property(e => e.KptId)
                    .ValueGeneratedNever()
                    .HasColumnName("KPT_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.KptDate)
                    .HasColumnType("date")
                    .HasColumnName("KPT_Date");

                entity.Property(e => e.KptDoi)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasColumnName("KPT_DOI")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

                entity.Property(e => e.KptDou)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasColumnName("KPT_DOU")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

                entity.Property(e => e.KptKpiId).HasColumnName("KPT_KPI_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.KptTarget)
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)")
                    .HasColumnName("KPT_Target");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.KptKpi)
                    .WithMany(p => p.KptKpiTargets)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.KptKpiId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__KPT_KPI_T__KPT_K__2FCF1A8A");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<KpvKpiValue>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.KpvId)
                    .HasName("PK_KPV_table");

                entity.ToTable("KPV_KPI_Values");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpvId)
                    .ValueGeneratedNever()
                    .HasColumnName("KPV_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpvDate)
                    .HasColumnType("date")
                    .HasColumnName("KPV_Date");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpvDoi)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasColumnName("KPV_DOI")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpvDou)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasColumnName("KPV_DOU")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpvKpiId).HasColumnName("KPV_KPI_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.KpvValue)
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)")
                    .HasColumnName("KPV_Value");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.KpvKpi)
                    .WithMany(p => p.KpvKpiValues)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.KpvKpiId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__KPV_KPI_V__KPV_K__3587F3E0");
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
```

}

**local.settings.json :**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
  "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
  "Values": {
    "sqlconnectionstring": "Server=tcp:progetto-kpi.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=progetto-kpi-database;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=progetto-kpi;Password=*********;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
    "ProviderName": "System.Data.SqlClient"


  }
}
```

**the problem :**

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       3.0.3568 Commit hash: e30a0ede85fd498199c28ad699ab2548593f759b  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.15828.0

Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
Missing value for AzureWebJobsStorage in local.settings.json. This is required for all triggers other than httptrigger, kafkatrigger, rabbitmqtrigger, orchestrationTrigger, activityTrigger, entityTrigger. You can run 'func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings <functionAppName>' or specify a connection string in local.settings.json.
```

**azuretosharepoint.csproj :**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <UserSecretsId>4e8db286-9c45-4574-b556-eb0a04ac345e</UserSecretsId>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.90" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper.Contrib" Version="2.0.78" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper.FluentMap" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper.SimpleCRUD" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.18.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup" Version="2.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{508349b6-6b84-4df5-91f0-309beebad82d}" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: This error is on localhost or at azure?

Comment: Try creating a separate & new local azure function project. Visual Studio Code had a great extension for this. Walk through the hello world tutorial and verify that you can get a simple HTTP trigger function working locally. Then compare the configs between the two projects. You're missing a setting somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Your local.settings.json seems to be incorrectly formatted. Try:

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "sqlconnectionstring": "YOURCONNECTIONSTRING",
        "ProviderName": "IDONTUSETHISVALUE-IN-MY-CONFIGS"
    }
}
```

Also, your connection string has the password blanked out. If you grab it from some parts of the Azure portal you'll get that. You might have done that intentionally, but if you didn't - remove the asterisks ^

A quick way to test if it is a local function configuration issue or an issue with your code:

1. Open new GitBash prompt / other terminal

```sh
func init TestMe --dotnet
cd TestMe
func new --name TestEndpoint --template "HTTP trigger" --authlevel "anonymous"
func start
```

To create a test timer trigger:

```sh
func new --name Timer --template "TIMER trigger"
```

Comment: True with a completely new function project too? And you've run dotnet restore, yeah?

Comment: the result :The function "TestEndpoint" was created successfully from the "HTTP trigger" template.

Comment: Excellent! Try creating a timer trigger. If that works you can, at least, copy your previous code from the last project over into this test project and go from there. Someone might have a more elegant solution, but this approach works for me when I'm hitting roadblocks: get a working environment, verify basics, add features one by one.

Answer (score 2):

The same happened to me, I had an Azure Function App working and after a some time started giving me the same exception.

My original project did not need any local.settings.json. So I created a new Azure Function Project App and copied and pasted in my old one the file local.settings.json.

Problem solved!