# Overriding appsettings.json values from Azure App settings

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a set of appsetting vaues as below. We are on Windows App service

```
"MainDomains": {
"Domains": [
  {
    "Id": "123456",        
    "Domain": "Technical",       
    "PolicyUrl": "https://www.mytechdomain.net",
    "LearningPoint": "https://www.mytechdomain.net",
    "Hostnames": [
      "https://localhost:4567",
      "http://localhost:34565",          
      "https://mytechdomain.latestlearn.com"
    ],
    "UsePreviewContent": true,
    "IsDefault": true,
    "OriginEmail": "info@techdomain.net",
    "mytechname": "Techdomain"
  }
]
```

}

How would i properly set these values in Azure App settings under configurations. I have already tried like property1:property2:0 --> xxxvalue. This does not seem to work however. What I am guessing is may be I have an array within another array. Where first array is the MainDomains and another array within the MainDomains array is the Domains.

Comment: Please try to use `__` instead of `:` as the separator. Something like  `MainDomains__Domains__Id`.

Comment: I missed to mention, we are on windows. So the __ works for linux i guess. However let me try

Comment: `__` is platform safe. According to the documentation `:` should work on Windows. Can you edit your question and give an actual example of what you're trying to set that is not working?

Comment: Yes Gaurav, I edited the topic. Here I am trying to set in App setting like below for example.

1. MainDomains:Domains:Id  --> 123456
2. MainDomains:Domains:Hostnames:0 --> https://localhost:4567

I found some information here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063167/using-an-array-in-azure-web-app-settings

Comment: I am not sure how to get this achieven in this case. An example for the above one is what I am looking for. I would need an example for setting (MainDomains:Domains:Id --> 123456) and (MainDomains:Domains:Hostnames:0 --> localhost:4567)

Answer (score 4):

You should set the app setting name with the same delimited format in the `appsettings.json`. But just like *Gaurav Mantri* said, use double underscore `__` rather than `:` on portal.

Refer to the description about [Configuration keys and values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configuration-keys-and-values):

> In environment variables, a colon separator may not work on all
> platforms. A double underscore, `__`, is supported by all platforms and
> is automatically converted into a colon `:`.

You could also have a look at the [official document about how to set App Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-app-settings).

Comment: I read somewhere __ works for linux and : works for Windows app services. Let me try anyways. Thank you